# Issue removing duplicate from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.5

My objective is to remove duplicate words from a paragraph in a text file (unicode) and generate a list of words. So far I have been able to remove unwanted characters & blank spaces. However I am having difficulty squeezing in the code to remove duplicate words. I tries using set but my values returned are null

This is my code.

```
with open ('words.txt',mode='r',encoding='utf8')as f:

   #open file and split each word
    for line in f:


        for word in line.split():

            #remove unwanted characters

            for char in ['।',',','’','‘','?']:
                if char in word:
                    word = word.replace(char,'')



              # remove blank line
            if word.strip():

                print (word)
```

Comment: Show us how you tried using a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you want to write the words in the same text again, this is the code:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

clean_list = set()
with open('words.txt', mode='r') as f:
    # open file and split each word
    for line in f:

        for word in line.split():

            # remove unwanted characters
            for char in ['।', ',', '’', '‘', '?']:
                if char in word:
                    print(char)
                    word = word.replace(char, '')

            # remove blank line
            if word.strip():
                clean_list.add(word)

# open the file again
with open('words.txt', mode='w+') as f:
    # clean file
    f.truncate()
    # writing the words
    for clean_word in clean_list:
        f.write(clean_word + '\n')
```

if you don't want to write it in the same file just change the last lines to this:

```
# open the file again
with open('new_words.txt', mode='w+') as f:
    # writing the words
for clean_word in clean_list:
    f.write(clean_word + '\n') # \n to save each word in a new line
```

**EDIT:**

I have used only set as @Copperfield suggested

Comment: thnx. If I were to write each word  as a list ? i.e `f.write(clean_word + new line)`

Comment: why not using set all the time? I don't see the point of going from list to set to list again

Comment: @choman in that case you should add with a end of line `f.write(clean_word + '\n')`

Comment: @Copperfield for some reason I believed he wanted to use a list, I've edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I define `clean` as a no-op function, you may want to remove punctuation etc so you have to define `clean` accordingly

```
def clean(w): return w
```

The unique words in your text can be collected in a set using a double list comprehension (technically, it's rather a *generator expression*), with the help of the `clean()` function

```
suw = set(clean(w) for line in open('words.txt') for w in line.split())
```

eventually you can remove the empty string from the set

```
suw.discard('')
```

To iterate on the members of the set (the unique words) use the familiar `for ... in ..:`construct

```
for uw in suw:
    # whatever
```

Comment: Python's `set`s have also a `.remove(…)` method that raises a `KeyError` if the item to remove is not present in the set — In this case it seems more convenient the more easy going `discard(…)` method

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below is pretty self-explanatory.

```py
with open("words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            words = []
            duplicates = set()

            for word in line.split():
                word = word.strip()
                if word:
                    for i in ['|', ',', '’', '‘', '?']:
                        word = word.replace(i, "")  # Doesn't create an error if i isn't in the word.

                    if word in duplicates:
                        pass  # do nothing
                    elif word in words:
                        words.remove(word)
                        duplicates.add(word)
                    else:
                        words.append(word)

            print(" ".join(words))  # or just `print " ".join(words)` for python2
```

Comment: `if word not in words` check is unnecessary since a set cannot contain duplicates.

Comment: It is necessary, as `words` contains all words it found before, and it shouldn't print duplicates. Note that the `if`-block contains the `print` statement as well.

Comment: Just print the set all at once at the end. That way it is not needed to check every word.

Comment: @IrmendeJong That may be more efficient, but sets don't have any order.

Comment: That is true, but nowhere was stated that the words should be printed in the order they appear in the source text.

Comment: @IrmendeJong You are right, but I just assumed that to be the case. I'll change my question accordingly.

Comment: @CodingLambdas I tried your code but the words at the beginning tend to retain their duplicate state. Also if i do not add if word.strip(): right before print (word) I get blank lines in the list . I have added the words.txt

Comment: @choman Sorry for my wrong answer, but your question was unclear regarding this issue. I thought you wanted to eliminate duplicates, but keep all words. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('words.txt',mode='r',encoding='utf8')
text = f.read()
for char in ['।',',','’','‘','?']:
    text=text.replace(char,'')
list_of_words=list(set(text.split()))
print(list_of_words)
```

Comment: the output is very strange. please check the words.txt